# Auto numbering textbox once i hit enter key

Tags: javascript, html

my target is when is when I type **"1"** on my textbox then hit **enter key**, the other textbox will be automatically do a numbering. For example:

> I have **3 textboxes**, once I type **1** on the first textbox, the
> other 2 textboxes value will be 2 and 3 and so on. How can I make this work?

```html
<input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" name="lb" />
<input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" name="lb" />
<input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" name="lb" />
```

Comment: ID's must be unique.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Learning how user events work on an `<input>` is easy to research as is how to get and set values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to not have readonly on the first field

I prefer to delegate and IDs must be unique

```js
const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("form-control") && tgt.type === "text" && e.code === "Enter") {
    let val = +tgt.value;
    const inputs = tgt.closest("form").querySelectorAll("input.form-control");
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].value = val;
      val++
    }
  }
})
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) { e.preventDefault() });
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" value="" class="form-control auto" placeholder="" required name="lb" />
  <input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control auto" placeholder="" required name="lb" />
  <input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control auto" placeholder="" required name="lb" />
</form>
```

but if you only want the first field to work

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".auto"); // I changed the id to a class
const first = inputs[0];
first.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  if (e.code === "Enter") {
    let val = +this.value;
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].value = val;
      val++
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control auto" placeholder="" required name="lb" />
<input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control auto" placeholder="" required name="lb" />
<input type="text" value="" readonly class="form-control auto" placeholder="" required name="lb" />
```

Comment: This is perfectly working. Wow, thank you so much. Really helpful. :D

Comment: Btw, is it okay for me to ask what's the difference between your answer and the 2nd person who answered my question? both answers my question perfectly. However, i don't know what's the difference.

Comment: @RainIe My first suggestion was to handle typing in numbers further down, like from field two. The second is identical to decpk, except I use a class to select the inputs and I use the e.code instead of e.keyCode and  +this.value instead of parseInt . Otherwise they are the same. There are only so many ways to skin this cat

Comment: Well explained. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `readonly` from the first `input` and make all `input` `type` as `number`

second and third input automatically increment by `1`.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs[0].addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  let value = parseInt(e.target.value);
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    inputs.forEach((inp, i) => {
      if (i !== 0) {
        inp.value = ++value;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" name="lb" />
<input type="number" value="" readonly class="form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" name="lb" />
<input type="number" value="" readonly class="form-control" placeholder="" required id="auto" name="lb" />
```

Comment: Btw, is it okay for me to ask what's the difference between your answer and the 2nd person who answered my question? both answers my question perfectly. However, i don't know what's the difference.

Comment: Who answered first, That's important. I've answered this question before anyone.

Comment: There could be many ways to solve a problem. So mplungjan may have used some other way.